# THREE.js: Loading model with JSONLoader loads only half of textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

After making a house model in blender I've exported it to three.js json format as a single object, but when adding it to scene I got half textures displayed and another half are just grey meshes.

JSON URL (with absolute texture images links): http://pobegushki.meetroll.net/inn1.js
Screenshot of what I get in blender and what I get in production: [image: http://touhou.ru/upload/78c7239c8306d7ee6d6ad6304935b3e1.jpg]

Also there are two instances of a barrel model which both has a perfectly mapped material. I tried setting barrel image as a material to floor (simple scaled box mesh), but nothing changed, it still remained grey.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TATATATAAAM! I've solved the problem (<s>the stupid way tbh</s>, but I got fully textured model).

Behold: http://touhou.ru/upload/56e75518ab580497358741bec62491ff.png

<s>Blender three.js export was creating empty textures for all untextured meshes I got, and I tried copy-pasting non-empty materials to empties. After thousands of page refreshes I got right materials assigned to right meshes.</s>

It took pretty much time, I think I should submit a bugreport :(

**UPDATE:** Here's why those materials were empty on export:

[image: http://touhou.ru/upload/9f9d879cbf4964f8343e610d6930fe1a.jpg]

On the first picture I've selected a mesh which had texture in production and on the second is one which didn't.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the file loaders/Loader.js (Rev56). At line 332, try to replace:

```
if ( m.mapDiffuse && texturePath ) {
```

by

```
if ( m.mapDiffuse && texturePath != null ) {
```

(same bug for all types of textures of course)

I stumbled upon this bug this week-end, where my textures were not displayed because `texturePath = ""`.

Comment: nope, paths are okay, got the same result. Half of textures work, half - not.